# LiveCycle Email Submit button xml and PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, adobe, acrobat, livecycle

I am using Adobe LiveCycle and trying to create a dynamic PDF and XML that I can then attach to an email to send it.

I so far have a completed PDF/XML, both of which I need to attach to an email. I am currently using an "Email Submit Button" which will allow me to sent either an xml OR PDF version of my file. What I am trying to do is attach both an XML and PDF version to an email via 1 "Email Submit Button"

I have looked around for a solution for quite some time now; I'm not convinced it can be done but if anyone has any suggestions for a workaround or solution then please share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you need to send both files via email instead of just the dynamic PDF?

If you have a LiveCycle server, you can always extract the XML from the submitted PDF and then pass it on to other services for processing. This is a typical use case scenario for LiveCycle form submission and it is recommended to use this approach.

Thanks,
Armaghan.